# Java error when running yuicompressor

Tags: java, php, symfony, assetic

I'm running the YUI compressor jar fine on my local dev server, but on the web server I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Assetic\Exception\FilterException' 
with message 'An error occurred while running: 
'/usr/bin/java' '-jar' 
'/path/to/includes/resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar' 
'-o' '/tmp/YUI-OUT-FGs8hh' '--type' 'js' '/tmp/YUI-IN-54MHwK' 
Error Output: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10) at 
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.10) at 
gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.10) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10) at 
gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.10) 
Input: /*! * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.2 * 
http://jquery.com/ * * Copyright 2011, John Resig * 
Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses. * 
http://jquery.org/license * * Incl in 
/path/to/includes/modules/Assetic/Exception/FilterException.php 
on line 40
```

I already checked with the server support, and they said to contact the developers. Any clue as to what this might be? I've also posted on Github, but no luck.

This is the Java version:

```
# java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.12-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: My first thought would be that `libgcj` was not installed on your server. I don't like when server support team just cuts me off with "concact the developer". For me, it's usually the sign to change the provider :)

Comment: These guys have been incredibly helpful and very good in general, but in any case thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: Ah, in that case OK :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [similar thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/432391/unable-to-start-tomcat6-java-error-exception-in-thread-main) or [this discussion](http://smartsvn.1697.n6.nabble.com/java-errors-when-running-smartsvn-sh-td3707810.html) - basically, you should contact your server support to change their java runtime environment to be something proper instead of GCJ. Using a regular JDK would solve this.

If they insist on using GCJ, they at least need to fix it to be runnable.

Comment: This was the fix; replaced GCJ with JDK and no problem :)